# How to organize Partial Views and the Jquery/Ajax code in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view where I display a list of entries, which works fine. For this purpose I have a partial view for a single entry. I iterate the entries in the model, and display the entries by calling this partial view:

```
 @model List<Entry>
 .....
 foreach(var entry in Model){
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Entry/_EntryItemView.cshtml", entry)
 }
```

Inside the _EntryItemView.cshtml view, there is an Edit button. When clicked, this button should display the Edit form, which is actually another partial view. For this purpose, I make a call to the ShowUpdateForm action of Entry controller which should return the strongly-typed Update Form (i.e., the partial view):

```
 @model Entry
 <div>@Model.Content</div>
 <a class="text-muted edit-entry">Edit</a>

 <script>
 $(".edit-entry").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ShowUpdateForm", "Entry")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: @Model,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $('body').append(data);
            $('#modalEditEntry').modal('show');
        }
     }).error(function (xhr, status) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
     });
  });
  </script>
```

Here is the ShowUpdateForm action called in ajax above:

```
    public ActionResult ShowUpdateForm(Entry model)
    {            
        return PartialView("~/Views/Entry/_EditEntryForm.cshtml", model);
    }
```

I wonder if my approach makes sense here, or do you recommend a different design? My concern is that the `$(".edit-entry").click()` will be included in the page multiple times thanks to the `foreach` loop. However, I cannot place the `$(".edit-entry").click()` in the parent view because I need to provide the `@Model` data in the `ajax` call and, the `@Model` is only available inside the _EntryItemView.cshtml.

Comment: Scripts should never be in partials. Move it to the main view. You do not (and should not) provide the model. Include a ID property identifying the model in the partial (e.g. a `data-id="@Model.ID"` attribute in the button) and then pass that the the method that generates your edit partial.

Comment: Or better, include a default edit form in the main view (hidden) and then just update the form controls with the values you have already included in the partial to avoid any ajax calls (refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FIwW4C) for an example)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think I got all this trouble for a day because I want to make the (update) form strongly-typed. But, I guess I does not have to, right? I thought it is more advantageous.

Comment: The update form will be strongly typed.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I thought for the form to be strongly typed, it has to be inside a Partial View with `@model Type` line. May I kindly ask you to post an answer?

Comment: Have a look at the fiddle I linked to. Is that the sort of thing your trying to do?